# Determine the natural domain of $f(x) = {\frac{\sqrt{N+3-x^2}}{\log (x)}}$.

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the following problem:

> Determine the natural domain of function $f$ given by $f(x) = {\frac{\sqrt{N+3-x^2}}{\log (x)}}$.

I know that whatever is within a radical cannot be negative and in the denominator cannot be $0$, but the $N$-value is throwing me off and I am not sure how to go about this particular question.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the square root to yield real numbers it must hold that $$ x^{2} \leq N+3, $$ meaning $$ x \in [-\sqrt{N+3}; \sqrt{N+3}]. $$
Now consider the denominator. First of all, the natural logarithm must take in positive values of $x$, so $x > 0$. Besides that, the denominator cannot be $0$. The logarithm assumes that value at $x=1$.

Now what you do is the intersection of all of these constraints to obtain your domain.  $$ x \in [-\sqrt{N+3}; \sqrt{N+3}] \cap (0;1)\cap(1;\infty). $$
Finally
$$ x \in (0;\sqrt{N+3}] \setminus    \{1\}. $$
If $N$ is such that the square root stays below $1$, the set substraction operation will just yield the interval $(0;\sqrt{N+3}] $.

Answer (score 0):

You need $x >0, \log x \neq 0$ and $x^{2}\leq N+3$. This translates to $0 <x<\sqrt {N+3}, x \neq 1$. So the domain is $(0,\sqrt {N+3})\setminus \{1\}$.